# How to get the aggregation values grouped by group names in mongodb using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a usecase where I'm having 3 collections. i.e, Templates,Groups and 1-dynamic collection of each template, which will be created right after the creation of a template.

Each `template` consists of `devices` and each `device` consists of a `groupId` of Groups collection. Dynamic collection stores the data pushed by the template's devices.

Now I need to find out the aggregation(sum) values of devices `grouped by groupName` of Groups collection.

Following are the sample data of my collections.

**Template Data**

```
{
  "_id": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
  "templateId": "27127206822",
  "devices": [
    {
      "deviceId": "waterTest",
      "_id": "5e0ae49629218b0a3861118f",
      "group": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",
    },{
       "deviceId": "Test",
       "_id": "5e0af166981f39410cd89b72",
       "group": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70"
    }]
}
```

**Dynamic Collection Data**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e0ae793b1384737a4f855cf",
    "template": "27127206822",
    "deviceId": "waterTest",
    "heat" : 20,
    "humidity" : 10
   },{
      "_id": "5e0ae7a2b1384737a4f855d0",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "deviceId": "waterTest",
      "heat" : 40,
      "humidity" : 20
   },{
      "_id": "5e0ae890b1384737a4f855d3",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "deviceId": "waterTest",
      "heat" : 60,
      "humidity" : 50
    },{
       "_id": "5e0af188981f39410cd89b73",
       "template": "27127206822",
       "deviceId": "Test",
       "heat": 60,
       "humidity": 50
   },{
      "_id": "5e0af196981f39410cd89b74",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "deviceId": "Test",
      "heat": 10,
      "humidity": 20
   }]
```

**Group Data**

```
[{
   "_id": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70",
   "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
   "groupName": "Flats"
 },{
    "_id": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",
    "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
    "groupName": "SPool"
 }]
```

Now look at the aggregate query I've written so far.

```
let templateId = "27127206822"; // Dynamic Collection

[err, templateData] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(templateId)
  .aggregate([
     {
          $lookup:{
             from:"templates",
             localField:"template",
             foreignField:"templateId",
             as:"template"
          }
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template"
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template.devices"
      },{
          $lookup:{
             from:"groups",
             localField:"template.devices.group",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"group"
          }
      },{
          $unwind:"$group"
      },{
          $group:{
             _id: "$groupData.groupName",
             heat:{$sum:"$heat"},
             humidity:{$sum:"$humidity"},
             count:{$sum:1}
          }
      }]));
```

Now, I need to get the sum of `heat & humidity` of every `device`  grouped by `groupName` of Group collection. But I'm getting the wrong data. i.e, **one group's sum is getting added to all other groups as well**.

**Returned Output **

```
//Am getting this Data
[
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "heat": 190,  // 2 group's data getting added in both the groups
    "humidity": 150,
    "count":5
  },{
    "_id": "SPool",
    "heat": 190,
    "humidity": 150,
    "count":5
  }]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "heat": 70,
    "humidity": 70,
    "count":2
  },{
    "_id": "SPool",
    "heat": 120,
    "humidity": 80,
    "count":3
  }]
```

Is there anything I've missed to get the required result?

Comment: Why are you tring to `$lookup` local `template` with foreign `templateId` ? I don't see any way to match between `"13435158964"` and any value from dynamic collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***:

I resolved this issue. Once the `$unwind:"$template.devices"` is done, every document gets each and every device of `$template.devices` array and with that documents gets duplicated.

So in order to get the correct answers, we need to match `deviceId` with the `deviceId of template.devices` object of every document.

The query would be,

```
[err, templateData] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(templateId)
  .aggregate([
     {
          $lookup:{
             from:"templates",
             localField:"template",
             foreignField:"templateId",
             as:"template"
          }
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template"
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template.devices"
      },{
          $match:{
            $expr:{
              $eq: [ "$deviceId","$template.devices.deviceId" ]
            }
          }
      },{
          $lookup:{
             from:"groups",
             localField:"template.devices.group",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"group"
          }
      },{
          $unwind:"$group"
      },{
          $group:{
             _id: "$groupData.groupName",
             heat:{$sum:"$heat"},
             humidity:{$sum:"$humidity"},
             count:{$sum:1}
          }
      }]));
```

By using this, we'll get the expected output. Which is,

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "heat": 70,
    "humidity": 70,
    "count":2
  },{
    "_id": "SPool",
    "heat": 120,
    "humidity": 80,
    "count":3
  }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) as a next aggregation stage and use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) both for counting and adding up:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$group.groupName",
        "count": { $sum: 1 },
        "heat": { $sum: "$heat" },
        "humidity": { $sum: "$humidity" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used it and working fine. But every group getting same results. Like this, ```[
        {
            "_id": "Pools",
            "heat": 1498,
            "humidity": 3924
        },
        {
            "_id": "Flat",
            "heat": 1498,
            "humidity": 3924
        },
        {
            "_id": "Swimming Pool",
            "heat": 1498,
            "humidity": 3924
        },
        {
            "_id": "Common Area",
            "heat": 1498,
            "humidity": 3924
        }
    ]```

Comment: @Aravind do they all refer to the same template ? You need to debug your pipeline - I would start with first `$lookup` to see if you're getting expected results, add next stage etc

Comment: Yeah, @mickl. They all refer to the same template. I think, I found the issue. Actually, every group's data getting added to all the groups. But how to differentiate the group names while getting the sums?

Comment: @Aravind could you edit your question and show an example of such situation ?

Comment: @Aravind I'm guessing that you're getting the data from more than one group because you're grouping by `groupName`, a better way would be to replace `groupName` with `_id` and add `groupName: { $first: "$groupName" }` to the `$group` stage

Comment: Ok, I'll test now.