# How to match values of an array object returned from mongo db lookup operation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the use case in which I need to perform aggregations on multiple collections. I've 3 collections (dynamic collection with template's unique Id, templates and groups).

While doing the aggregations, I got the wrong results. i.e, am getting the unmatched results. I need to get the data whose device id matches with the device id of template's devices.

**Sample Data**

```
db={
  "templates": [
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
      "templateId": "27127206822",
      "devices": [
        {
          "deviceId": "waterTest",
          "_id": "5e0ae49629218b0a3861118f",
          "group": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",

        },
        {
          "deviceId": "Test",
          "_id": "5e0af166981f39410cd89b72",
          "group": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "_id": "5e0af11d981f39410cd89b70",
      "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
      "groupName": "Flats"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae41d29218b0a3861118d",
      "template": "5e0ae38729218b0a3861118b",
      "groupName": "SPool"
    }
  ],
  "dynamic": [
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae793b1384737a4f855cf",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "heat": 20,
      "humidity": 10,
      "deviceId": "waterTest"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae7a2b1384737a4f855d0",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "heat": 40,
      "humidity": 20,
      "deviceId": "Test"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0ae890b1384737a4f855d3",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "heat": 60,
      "humidity": 50,
      "deviceId": "waterTest"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0af188981f39410cd89b73",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "heat": 60,
      "humidity": 50,
      "deviceId": "Test"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0af196981f39410cd89b74",
      "template": "27127206822",
      "heat": 10,
      "humidity": 20,
      "deviceId": "waterTest"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query**

```
var y = payload.year, m = payload.month;
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

firstDay = moment(firstDay).tz('Asia/Kolkata').toISOString();
lastDay = moment(lastDay).tz('Asia/Kolkata').toISOString();

[err, templateData] = await to(db.dynamic
  .aggregate([
     { 
      $match: {
        "entryDayTime":{
             $lt: new Date(lastDay),
             $gte: new Date(firstDay)
          }
       }
      },{
          $lookup:{
             from:"templates",
             localField:"template",
             foreignField:"templateId",
             as:"template"
          }
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template"
      },{ 
          $unwind:"$template.devices"
      },{
          $lookup:{
             from:"groups",
             localField:"template.devices.group",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"group"
          }
      },{
          $unwind:"$group"
      },{
          $group:{
             _id: "$groupData.groupName",
             heat:{$sum:"$heat"},
             humidity:{$sum:"$humidity"},
             count:{$sum:1}
          }
      },{
            $project:{
               "heat":1,"humidity":1,"count":1,
               "template.devices.group":1,
               "template.devices.deviceId":1,
               "group.groupName":1
            }
        }]).toArray());
```

**Returned result for above query**

```
//Am getting this Data
[
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "heat": 190,  // 2 group's data getting added in both the groups
    "humidity": 150
  },{
    "_id": "SPool",
    "heat": 190,
    "humidity": 150
  }]
```

**Expected output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Flats",
    "heat": 70,
    "humidity": 70,
    "count":2
  },{
    "_id": "SPool",
    "heat": 120,
    "humidity": 80,
    "count":3
  }]
```

In the above results, am getting unmatched device's data being added in the sums. How to get only the matched device's data?

Answer (score 0):

Please use lookup with pipeline, we can get you want to result

```
 db.dynamic.aggregate([
    {
     $lookup: {
      from: "templates",
      localField: "template",
      foreignField: "templateId",
      as: "template"
    }
  },

  {
    $unwind: "$template"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "template._id": 0,
      "template.templateId": 0
      'template.devices': {
        $filter: {
           input: "$template.devices",
           as: "item",
           cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.deviceId",$deviceId ] }
        }
     }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please also help me with the similar issue? please see this link, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533118/how-to-remove-the-duplication-of-aggregation-values-in-mongodb-using-node-js/59535819?noredirect=1#comment105251382_59535819)

Comment: @Aravind does this question resolves your question? If not can you update your question with the expected output?

Comment: yeah @SuleymanSah, I've the above issue while finding the sums grouped by above group names. Can you please go through this? I'll update this question.

Comment: @Aravind you updated this question as same as the other question, why?

Comment: because this is the problem i have. I found the issue, before grouping the varibales, i need to match the deviceId's in dynamic collection object and template's devices. But that's not happening. Because of that am getting wrong data. ]